# Laptop with two variants, identical motherboards: Graphics card addition possible?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express, integrated-graphics, pci, intel-graphics

Ok, I know a gazillion people have asked countless times about the possibility of adding a graphics card to a laptop, but this one has a twist:

I got a Samsung NP300E5Z laptop recently, and the laptop model has a few different variants. Mine is a NP300E5Z-A0GAE. It has Intel HD Graphics built into the Sandy Bridge processor, and while light gaming for me is now better than it was on my old Dell Inspiron laptop, I would have liked it if the performance was above average.

Now to the point: One of the variants of the laptop is the NP300E5Z-S01AE, but it comes with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 520MX Graphics card. Link to specs: http://www.samsung.com/pk/consumer/computers-peripherals/laptops/essential/NP300E5Z-S01AE-spec

My laptop and that one are identical in ALL aspects, the only differences are the amount of RAM and the presence of discrete graphics. Even the motherboard is the same, both laptops have the  Intel HM65 chipset. These are the same model, but one comes with the Nvidia, and one does not.

So... if there any chance at all that I could, somehow get a graphics card on mine? I've heard that most laptops have the GPU soldered to the motherboard, but that's also not always the case. My laptop has 3 PCI-Express slots and one PEG Gen1/Gen2 slot free.

Comment: I don't think your laptop does have 3 PCI slots free at all, laptops just aren't built like that!  Both laptops would need to be using MXM sockets for their GPU's which is unfortunately unlikely.

Comment: Well, I did a full system information check using SIW... and it clearly says that the system has 3 PCI-Express slots and one PEG Gen1/Gen2 slot free. They're listed as "Available" and the other two PCI-Express slots are shown as "In use."

Comment: Ah I thought that might be what you were seeing.  Technically it does have free PCI slots (as per chipset supports), physically though there's no such thing inside.  So unless *both* laptops have MXM sockets (this would be in the spec), you can't do it.  Laptops aren't built with this upgrade in mind.